# Microsoft Teams JS SDK initialization timed out when try to implement custom tab in Teams

Tags: reactjs, next.js, microsoft-teams-js

We are facing an issue in the Microsoft Teams JS SDK

```
"@microsoft/teams-js": "2.9.1"
```

When I am running inside the team environment, I am getting this error Error:

```
SDK initialization timed out.
```

When I am running the app in Chrome, I am getting this error:

```
VM424:1 Error: Initialization Failed. No Parent window found.
```

My dependencies in `package.json` files are are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.11.0",
    "@fluentui/react-components": "^9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.5.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
},
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKbdC.png)

Getting this error in chrome and edge and inside microsoft teams as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ma6.png)

I want to initialize the teams sdk and then want to perform task on the custom tab.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.